# Drupal 7 Profile 2 list field optgroup in options

Tags: 7, users

I came across a requirement to add a list field from profile 2 with optgroups. I know that cck has the "PHP" option where you can return allowed values for a list box and can do optgroup there. But can anyone tell me how to do it in profile 2 select list type field ?

Thanks.